# Telegram bot can't receive data from table with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, telegram-bot

I'm creating bot for Telegram.
And everything was OK, until I started to connect my bot with my database.
So, I've created table with fields `"date","day","schedule"`.

And I want to make my bot to get a schedule by data from table.

But it can't. And I don't know why.

Here is a part of my code which belongs to DB connection.

```
<?php

//Connect to db with my params
$db = new mysqli('###', '###', '###', '###');

//Receive today's date
$date = date('Y-m-d');

/*
 * Schedule - is what I'm looking for(some text in the table), knu - table's name
 * date - table's field with date(format YYYY-MM-DD)
 */

$query =    "SELECT schedule FROM knu WHERE `date` = '$date'";
$res = $db->query($query);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();


//Send message to user
if($message == "a")
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $answer = $row;
    sendMessage($chatId, $answer);
}
```

And this code doesn't work. I've tried a lot of times with different ways but still no answer with my bot.
**What's wrong with my code and how to make it work?**

Comment: Have you checked `$row` value?

Comment: `$row` isn't a string, it's an array. You probably want `$answer['schedule']`.

Comment: @AliHamze, yeah, I want to receive schedule. Please, help me how to correctly do it, if it's not hard for you :)

Comment: @AliHamze oh YEA, I've got it! :)
Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Grynets Awesome, I just posted it as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row` isn't a string, it's an array. You probably want `$answer['schedule']` or even just `$row['schedule']` allowing you to remove the line `$answer = $row;`.